# How can I get the path of the file being downloaded by aria2?

Tags: command-line, downloads, download-manager, downloaders

I want to write a bash function to both start downloading a file and open it in a video player; I don't know how to get the path of the file being downloaded though:

```bsh
function dl-and-stream() {
  aria2c "$1" &
  sleep 30
  mpv #What to put here
}
```

PS: This is not my only use case, and I’m aware of `--out`, but I like to keep the original file name.

Update: My use cases can be fulfilled via `--on-download-complete` (and other event handlers), but I still prefer not using that if possible. (Because they need the creation of additional script files.)

Comment: Why do you start `arai2c` _in the background_ and start `mpv` before `aria2c` has even figured out how to access the URL and possibly followed some redirections?

Comment: @PerlDuck Ik, I just wanted to show a simple example. I actually use youtube-dl for this function, and keep retrying mpv till it successfully opens the file.

Comment: If you use `youtube-dl` then you should probably ask about `youtube-dl` and not about some other tool that is not so widely known. Consider we figure out that `aria2c` writes the output filename to `/etc/var/log/foo/output.file.name` and we'd give you the advice to read that file. Of what help would that be for `youtube-dl`?

Comment: @PerlDuck I don’t have a problem with this particular function (because I know how to get the path from youtube-dl), it’s just a simple example to illustrate the question. And you should totally try aria2, it’s an incredible download manager. I have used prefer much all famous download managers, and a lot of not famous ones. Aria2 is just in its own league. :)

Answer (score 1):

`aria2c` provides an `--on-download-start` option which lets you run a command as soon as the download started. To use it to start playing the file, write a script with

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
mpv "$3"
```

and run `aria2c` like that in your function:

```bsh
aria2c --on-download-start /path/to/script "$1"
```

That has the extra advantage that you don’t need to `sleep` for a fixed amount of time, which may not be enough in some cases. In fact, you don’t need a function at all with this solution, a simple `alias` does it:

```bsh
alias dl-and-stream='aria2c --on-download-start /path/to/script'
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately aria2 renames the files sometimes.

Comment: @HappyFace How? Please include this information in your question!

Comment: It’s downloading files from the internet, and pretty much all downloaders sometimes don’t just use everything from the last slash onwards. I don’t know the details of how they do it.

Comment: I don’t have an example at hand, but this textual approach won’t be able to deal with them, since the new name is gotten from the server.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it. It’s just that I have mentioned this approach in my question, and dislike the need to create additional scripts. But thanks! 

Comment: Fair enough, but I knew of all the event handlers I tried to use them without creating files, using zsh’s =(), but unfortunately that didn’t work.

Comment: Apparently `aria2c` calls the command quoted, that’s really sloppy. Unfortunately that prevents something like `--on-download-start 'sh -c "mpv \"$2\""'`. If you already knew and tried stuff, why didn’t you add this information to your question? Please do so!